# How can I change playback device "default format" using a batch file?

Tags: audio, batch, batch-file

I'm having issues with my speakers where they will crackle randomly until the audio format is changed. (I go back and forth between both studio quality options) The crackling can start as frequently as every 3 minutes but also go days without it happening. This happens with multiple different computers, it's some issue with my speakers I eventually need to replace.

How can I more easily change the audio format without having to go into the speaker settings, my device, advanced, ect every time. Is there a batch file I can write that will switch between two audio formats?

The audio format tab:

[image: The audio format tab]

Comment: This isn't exactly what you want, but imo you should just set the audio format to default, maybe your speakers will stop crackling